# FPDF current date incorrect

Tags: php, html, fpdf

Has anyone had trouble with the current date displaying incorrectly using FPDF? I have the date on the footer of the page and it says 8/6/2015. I am in eastern time zone and it should be 8/5/2016

```
$currentdate = date("m-d-Y");
```

Comment: check your server time zone. if server time zone is not matching with your time zone change default time zone via your script. this will solve your problem.

Comment: Add the code where you put the value of `$currentdate` into the footer of your `fpdf` object.

Comment: This what I have now                                                                                                                                $footer = '  Page: ' . $pagenumber . ' of ' .$totalpages . '   Date: ' . $currentdate;

Comment: And how to you put the `$footer` in your `fpdf`?

Comment: Here is a section of code for the page                                                                                       
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);   
      $pagenumber += 1;  
      $footer = '                   Page: ' . $pagenumber . ' of ' . $totalpages . '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Date: ' . $currentdate;

Answer (score 0):

First set your timezone using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/it/function.date-default-timezone-set.) and then try,

```
date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
$currentdate = date("m-d-Y");
echo $currentdate; //result : 08-05-2016
```

Comment: @SteveD, i have tried on `phpfiddle.org` and it works

Comment: Where do I put it? When I replaced $currentdate = date("m-d-Y"); with your code the page goes down